# Is there a difference between "maltreat" & "ill-treat"?

Tags: verbs, differences, synonyms

Is there a difference between *maltreat* and *ill-treat* or are they interchangeable, since both refer to rougher treatment?

Comment: The definitions provided (by Oxford Languages) when you google each word would seem to answer your question: _"treat (a person or animal) cruelly or with violence"_ for _maltreat_, and _"act cruelly toward (a person or animal)"_ for _ill-treat_; In other words, they seem to mean roughly (:)) the same thing. Did you consult a dictionary before asking here? Please [edit] your question to add some details (like an example sentence or two) and explain what precisely you'd like to know, beyond the dictionary definitions.

Comment: It would be unfortunate if this question were closed. Currently there are two votes for closing the question as answerable by a dictionary, but consulting a dictionary will only confirm what the OP already knows, that they are very close in meaning. Dictionary definitions will not directly answer whether there are, despite the obvious similarities, some subtle differences between them.

Comment: @jsw28 It would be simple for OP to add dictionary definitions and then query any slight differences. ELL was established largely to help those needing help with the basics.

Comment: @jsw29 As with most (if not all) synonyms, there are—maybe necessarily—nuances. But a dictionary still may point out these nuances are negligible. If the words were completely different, a dictionary would have similarly pointed that out, and the question could have been closed for the same reason without second thought.

Answer (score 1):

Even though dictionaries define **ill-treat** as a transitive verb, it hasn't been used with a direct object very much for about a century now and more often appears as the noun **ill-treatment** and the adjective formed from the past participle, **ill-treated**.

The distinctions I draw below are based on how I've seen and heard the words used; they're not an attempt to construct a consensus definition from the various dictionaries.

A person who has been **ill-treated** has been treated unkindly,  disrespectfully, or unfairly, or subjected to some kind of emotional cruelty or torment. Ill-treatment does not extend to physical abuse.

A person or animal that has been **maltreated** has been treated cruelly or inhumanely, including being subjected to pain or profound deprivation.

Comment: Please write answers based on reliable sources, not anecdotes. "How I've seen and heard the words used" doesn't count.

Comment: @alphabet  Are you calling me unreliable?  Do you disagree with the above? I could cite examples of the above, but they would be anecdotal. That's the only kind of evidence there is for the meaning of words, ultimately, since dictionaries are based on what is found in the wild.  Lexicographers merely describe what they find. They don't "assign" meaning to words.

Comment: To be clear: I don't think that you personally are uniquely unreliable, only that vague anecdotal evidence from a single individual isn't a good basis for answering questions; dictionaries are generally based on more substantive (e.g. corpus) research.

Comment: (For example: research would show that *ill-treatment* is in fact used to describe physical abuse, not just emotional mistreatment, as in [this article.](https://theguardian.com/world/2023/mar/30/refugees-widespread-physical-ill-treatment-council-of-europe) I don't mean that as a specific criticism of your answer, just as a general warning about the need to do research of *some* sort.)

Comment: Yes, but they use the noun "ill-treatment" and qualify it with the premodifier "physical", **physical ill-treatment**.  Now this is to be ill-treated: "People on the move were subject to pushbacks, expulsion from European states, either by land or sea, without having asylum claims heard."

Comment: You claimed that "ill-treatment does not extend to physical abuse" without qualification, which isn't true. My point is: this is why it's so important to do research and cite it instead of just following your intuition.

Comment: I will qualify my statement and say that in AmE,  **ill-treated** is normally used as I said it was. We would *not* say that someone who had been locked away in a gulag and tortured or fed starvation rations had been "ill-treated" since iIl-treatment doesn't encompass extend to such extremes of abuse or deprivation, to physical violence or abuse. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=physical+abuse%2Cphysical+ill-treatment&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: But this United Nations document uses **ill-treatment** in exactly the way I say that it is not typically used in American English: https://docstore.ohchr.org/SelfServices/FilesHandler.ashx?enc=6QkG1d%2FPPRiCAqhKb7yhskvE%2BTuw1mw%2FKU18dCyrYrZhDDP8yaSRi%2Fv43pYTgmQ5n7dAGFdDalfzYTJnWNYOXxeLRAIVgbwcSm2ZXH%2BcD%2B%2F6IT0pc7BkgqlATQUZPVhi

Comment: Great, an Ngram search! Now you've done research using a reliable source, and you can cite it. That's all I was asking for.